# Prove that a matrix is a scalar matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Given $k\in\mathbb{N}$, an invertible matrix $M$, and the equation:

> $(M^{-1}AM)^k=3I$

I need to prove $A$ is a scalar matrix, without using eigenvalues. I understand why it's true, but can't prove it.

Comment: The lhs can be written as $M^{-1}A^kM$ so you can rearrange for $A^k$ and show that that is a scalar matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the other answers it is easy to show that $A^k$ must be a scalar matrix. But note that this does not means that $A$ is also a scalar matrix.
As a counterexample use:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\2&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for $k=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $M^{-1}AMM^{-1}AM= M^{-1}A^2M$, i.e. the 'interior' $M$s cancel out. By induction
$$ (M^{-1}AM)^k = M^{-1}A^kM$$
Now multiply your original equation from the left with $M$ and from the right with it's inverse.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$aI = \left(M^{-1}AM\right)^k = \underbrace{\left(M^{-1}AM\right) \cdot \left(M^{-1}AM\right) \cdots \left(M^{-1}AM\right)}_{k \text{ times}} = M^{-1} A^k M \implies M(aI)M^{-1} = A^k$$
Hence, we have
$$A^k = aI$$
Now conclude what you want.

Comment: why does $M^k=M$ and $M^{-k}=M^{-1}$?

Comment: @ntrch $M^k$ is not $M$. Multiply out the product, you will obtain $MM^{-1}$ which is identity.